# Which assembly should I add to PCL to get Prism 6 PubSubEvent class enabled?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I try to use PCL (Portable Class Library) as common class library in my Prism 6 modular WPF MVVM application. As IDE I use MS VS 2015 Professional. When I try to define (in PCL added to my application solution) class for loosely coopled event as the following:

```
public class UserAuthorizationLevelDeterminedEvent : PubSubEvent<UserAuthorizationLevel>
{
}
```

Then the following error has place: *The type or namespace name 'PubSubEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*. I try to add the following using directive:

```
using Prism.Events;
```

But in this case the following error has place: *The type or namespace name 'Prism' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*. When I try to install Prism.Wpf or Prism.Core via NuGet (in PCL' assemblies) then the following error has place: *Failure recovery package. Rolling back the changes to the package «PCL' name»*. What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

**P.S.** May be using of simple ClassLibrary project is more suitable in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You want a PCL, well, if you want the code inside to be *portable*, that is, between different framework versions or platforms like PC, phone, android and so on.

If portability is not a requirement, go for a regular class library.

Answer (score 0):

The Prism.Core package contains the IEventAggregator and is the only package that supports PCL.  Prism.WPF requires a class library.